# SpotFire 11.4.1: Reload All Data automatically once a day instead of having to go to each dashboard and hit: Data -> Refresh all Data

Tags: spotfire

I have Spotfire dash boards that are connected to the data in our database through Microsoft SQL Server. I have to go into Spotfire dashboard everyday and hit "reload all data" under the data tab.

Is there a way to have that run automatically everyday?

I do have access the automation service but am not sure if I need to learn how to use that or not.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

For what you are describing, you will want to use scheduling and routing, not automation services. This functionality will allow you to set a schedule at which analysis will be loaded and data refreshed.

https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire_server/11.0.0/doc/html/TIB_sfire_server_tsas_quick_start_help/server/topics/scheduled_updates_to_analyses.html